# Probability of obtaining an eigenvalue for a degenerate spectrum of continuous eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to find the probability of obtaining an eigenvalue $\lambda$ which has a degenerate set of eigenstates $\phi_1(x)$, $\phi_2(x)$, and $\phi_3(x)$. Now, I want to know if this approach is correct for doing this:

$$p=\left|\int\phi_1^*(x)\psi(x)dx\right|^2+\left|\int\phi_2^*(x)\psi(x)dx\right|^2+\left|\int\phi_3^*(x)\psi(x)dx\right|^2$$

Now I'm not sure where this approach is the correct one. I know that in the bra-ket notation, I have to take a similar approach. But with these being continuous functions, I want to know if the norm has to be inside the integral or outside the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is correct. The probability is indeed given by

$$p=\left|\int\phi_1^*(x)\psi(x)dx\right|^2+\left|\int\phi_2^*(x)\psi(x)dx\right|^2+\left|\int\phi_3^*(x)\psi(x)dx\right|^2$$

The expression $\langle\phi\vert\psi\rangle$ is an inner product. For the case where you have a finite dimensional space, you have

$$\vert\phi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \\. \\. \\ \phi_n \end{pmatrix}$$

Similarly, for $\vert\psi\rangle$ and so the bra-ket is given by
$$\langle\phi\vert\psi\rangle = \sum_a \phi_a^*\psi_a$$

In a continuous space, we rewrite the sum as an integral like $\int\phi^*(a)\psi(a)da$ and the square of this integral represents the probability.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My main problem was in the continuous functions (I was working through a problem that just didn't "feel right" when using this approach).